# How to use validator to change border color of formcontrolname in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a formcontrol where I want to change the color when the field is invalid I have tried the following as most examples do the same:

```
 <input 
        formControlName="personNameField"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Bitte eingeben"
        [ngClass]="{'error': personNameField.errors}"
        ></input>
```

My ts formcontrol is generated like this:

```
    form = this.builder.group({
    personNameField: new FormControl('',
      [Validators.required]),
  });

  getName(){
    this.form.get('personNameField')
  }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errors')
```

any idea what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I added the getter and removed the question mark but still the bordering does not work only error message is shown.

UPdate2:

```
.error {
    // underline input field on error
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    color: red;
}
```

What I want
[image: target image]

What I get
[image: what i get]

Comment: Do you want to show error on touch or after submitting?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
[ngClass]="{'error': form.get('personNameField')?.errors}"
```

Comment: hey thanks this brought me one step further but now there is just one big rectangle around the label and input. I only want to change the border color do you have an idea on how to change my scss? I updated my code

Comment: Sorry I can not understand what you are trying to do. Please show with an image.

Comment: I did add pictures

Comment: Your html in this post does not have a label. Please update your post so that it includes all the part "What I get".

Answer (score -1):

so simple for input validation using bootstrap class :
First in you HTML file we have :

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">title</label>
        <input id="title" type="text" formControlName="title" class="form- 
       control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': isCategorySubmitted && 
        categoryFormInfo.title.errors}" />
        </div>
```

so in your ts file :

```
isCategorySubmitted = false;

initFormBuilder() {
this.categoryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

}

```
  get categoryFormInfo() {
return this.categoryForm.controls;
```

}

```
  submit() {
this.isCategorySubmitted = true;
if (this.categoryForm.invalid) {
  return;
}

  // do your code after the submit

}
```

by this, you can validate the input so simply .